# How much money can minors receive as gifts?

Tags: united-states, tax-law, minor

What tax restrictions apply to minors receiving large monetary gifts from non-relatives? How much can they receive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to an overview by TurboTax:

> If you give people a lot of money, you might have to pay a federal
>   gift tax. But the IRS also allows you to give up to $14,000 in 2016 to
>   any number of people without facing any gift taxes, and without the
>   recipient owing any income tax on the gifts.

Generally, if it kept under $14,000 you should not face any consequences.

[For gifts more than $14,000](https://ttlc.intuit.com/questions/2542778-if-i-receive-a-gift-of-say-50-000-from-a-friend-and-i-give-that-person-a-gift-12-24-months-later-can-that-person-claim-my-gift-on-his-taxes-and-not-have-to-pay-income-on-that-money-assume-neither-of-us-is-near-our-gift-limit):

> Gifts are neither taxable or deductible on your tax return.   Any gift
>   to an individual that exceeds $14,000 in a year requires a separate
>   gift tax return to be filed (form 709) by the giver - the receiver of
>   the gift does not report anything.  It will not be immediately
>   taxable, but will reduce your lifetime exclusion.

However, it is always best to consult a CPA.

Comment: I think there is also a lifetime limit, and I recall something about __ gifts to minors adding more detail, but I know I'm missing a word.